# Docker service intercommunication troubleshoot

Tags: mysql, symfony, docker, pdo, docker-compose

Attempting to dockerize a Symfony 3.1 application, I run Docker for Windows:

- Docker Desktop Version: 2.0.0.3
- Engine Version: 18.09.2
- Compose Version: 1.23.2

Here is my current `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/dev/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./../..:/app
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
      - php:php
  php:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/dev/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./../..:/app
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
  mariadb:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/dev/mariadb/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=todo_list
      - MYSQL_USER=todo_list
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=todo_list
volumes:
  database:
```

Here are my `Dockerfile`s for each of the 3 services above:

`nginx`:

```
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY docker/dev/nginx/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY . /app
```

`php`:

```
FROM php:7.3.6-fpm-alpine3.10
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql
COPY docker/dev/php/config/php.conf ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/default.ini
COPY . /app
```

`mariadb`:

```
FROM mariadb:10.3
COPY docker/dev/mariadb/config/mariadb.conf /etc/mysql/conf.d/default.cnf
RUN chmod 0444 /etc/mysql/conf.d/default.cnf
```

Running `docker-compose up`, everything seems fine, no inconsistencies or error/warning detected in the services logs…

The Symfony `parameters.yml` in which is defined database access and credentials looks like this:

```
parameters:
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     3306
    database_name:     todo_list
    database_user:     todo_list
    database_password: todo_list
```

With this configuration I am able to run successfully the Symfony console commands:

```sh
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Which means that **in this context**, the app has access to the database.

But when I interact with the app via HTTP (`http://localhost` in web browser), so via the docker service `nginx`, I get a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

So I change the `parameters:database_host` entry in the `parameters.yml` from `127.0.0.1` to `172.31.0.1` (which is the current IP address of the `mariadb` container) and this time I can interact with the app via HTTP, without any problem for it to access to the database, but instead, I get a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` when attempting to access to the database via the Symfony console.

I suspected a Docker Compose misconfiguration but after checking and rechecking the Docker doc, tutorials, example GitHub repos, and similar SE questions, for hours, I don't get what I'd be doing wrong…

Comment: You need to use the Docker Compose service name of the database service (`mariadb`) as the hostname; `localhost` in Docker always means "this container".  The `links:` are unnecessary and potentially cause problems.

Comment: `mariadb` resolves to `172.31.0.1` so using `mariadb` as value for the `parameters:database_host` entry leads to the result I have already experimented with this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidMaze said in the comment, remove the `links` from the docker-compose file and use the name of the service instead of the address (`mariadb` instead of `127.0.0.1`). This way it will work for connections coming from inside docker.

This way, as you have already seen, it stops working for connections coming from outside docker (neve used Symfony console but I assume it's outside of docker). To work around it you have at least two ways:

1. quick and dirty, add a line in your hosts file (on windows, the file should be at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`) like
   this: `127.0.0.1 mariadb`, this will instruct windows to resolve
   `mariadb` as `127.0.0.1`
2. configure your project to use different config files depending on if you are connecting from inside or outside docker (can't tell you
   exactly how, it really depends on your project structure)

IMHO option 1 is acceptable for development machines.

Comment: You got what confused me, thank you. Little rectification tho, the `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file entries are structured like this instead: `127.0.0.1 mariadb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 127.0.0.1 in your parameter.yml but you can use 'mariadb' instead since you defined it in your links section.
Now links is described as deprecated so it will work but you'll probably want to go with networking.

```
 version: "3.6"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/dev/nginx/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./../..:/app
    ports:
      - 80:80
  php:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/dev/php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./../..:/app
  mariadb:
    build:
      context: ./../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/dev/mariadb/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=todo_list
      - MYSQL_USER=todo_list
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=todo_list
volumes:
  database:
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge 
    name: frontend #or whatever custom name since 3.5      
  backend:        
    driver: bridge
    name: backend #or whatever custom name since 3.5
```